# Airflow doesnt see my local file: ' FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '

Tags: python, airflow

I'm working on airflow with docker. My python file has json path like:

> '/home/user_name/airflow2-local_setup/credentials/my_file.json'

I'm using it my python file in dags directory. In web ui got an error

```
    Broken DAG ...  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user_name/airflow2-local_setup/credentials/my_file.json'
```

How can i give file path to airflow?

Comment: You need to mount that file as a volume into your container. The docker container will otherwise have no access to that file on your system

Comment: have you copied the file into the image defined on your dockerfile?

Comment: @kucing_terbang That may solve the issue in the short term, but credentials/configuration should be excluded from the image and mounted in at runtime where possible

Comment: I guess, it depends on the context. But, true, usually it will be loaded once in runtime. But, I guess that is another question different from what op's asking

Comment: i got it. After use copy command in dockerfile, should i determine path according to docker path or my local?